# Error when creating MFP adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server, worklight-studio, mfp

Getting error when trying to create MFP Http adapter in MFP 8.0.
Please find the error below.

```
 No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in
 the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
 available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\\.m2\repository),
 central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
```

[image]

Comment: What version of the CLI are you using?

Comment: 8.0.0-2018040312

Comment: Which step you have taken ? Are you using MFP CLI or Eclipse to create Adapter ?? Edit your question and write these things.

Comment: MFP CLI for creating Adapters

Comment: any updates on the above

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to download maven dependencies through CLI.

Might be you are under proxy or network issue that blocking maven urls.

Comment: i am not under a proxy and still getting it

Comment: Have you installed Maven ? Is your mfpdev-cli latest version ?